# Android AlarmManager with BroadcastReceiver Inner Class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to implement an AlarmManager using an inner BroadcastReceiver class. Here is my inner class:

```
public class MyAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   

         Toast.makeText(context, "alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }

     public void setAlarm(Context context) {
         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi);
     }
}
```

Since its an inner class I understand that I have to dynamically register the receiver. In my main activity I have the following code:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    MyAlarm alarm = new MyAlarm();
    alarm.setAlarm(this);
    this.registerReceiver(alarm, filter);
```

The alarm isn't firing for me.

Comment: Is there any reason it must be an inner class? Standard practice is to unregister your dynamically registered receivers when the Activity that registered them goes away. You are probably better off moving this to its own class and declaring it in your manifest.

Comment: I wanted to call a method in my main activity and this way seemed to be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't use a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` with `AlarmManager`, because with localBroadcast the data doesn't leave the application, it works within the app process (local), and the alarm manager works with different processes.

Actually the pending intent would be the "problem" here:

> The PendingIntent class provides a mechanism for creating intents that
>   can be fired on your application's behalf by another application at a
>   later time

As you can see by definition the pendingIntent works with different processes. That would be the reason you cannot make it work with a local broadcast.

You would need to register the receiver in the manifest, and as @leesei said, you have to declare the inner class as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details of your project, I'm inclined to say don't use a receiver, use a Handler and post a delayed runnable while your activity is in the foreground.

```
private static final long DELAY = 10000;
private Handler handler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handler = new Handler();
}

protected void onStart() {
    handler.postDelayed(doSomethingRunnable, DELAY);
}

protected void onStop() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(doSomethingRunnable);
}

private Runnable doSomethingRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomething(); // the method you wanted to call
        handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like my method in my main activity to always execute periodically even when the app is in the background or closed. Will this achieve that?

Comment: No, but if that's what you want then you should not be using an Activity. Activities in the background can be killed any time by the system. You should use a BroadcastReceiver or a Service that is declared in the manifest. If it's something that should occur regardless of the state of your Activity, then the Activity is the wrong place to put that code. Perhaps if you describe more what the end result should be, we can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: I just had a method I wanted to execute periodically even when the app is closed or backgrounded. Is there a way to periodically run this method or is the best way to move the code to a service? The activity has a lot of state information so it'd be much more convenient if I could just directly call and run that method.

Comment: Yes, move it to a service. You can use an IntentService if it's code that you may not want to run on the Main thread. IntentService also stops itself when it finishes executing its task, so you don't need to worry about handling its lifecycle yourself.

Comment: Should I be using AlarmManager + Service or just IntentService? And could you please refer me to some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Docs: [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

```
public class MyService extends IntentService() {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService"

    public MyService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // do your work here
    }
}
```

Somewhere else, possibly in your activity, you will create an alarm to run your service periodically:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pi);
```

I'm not sure what your use case it, but once every ten seconds seems a bit aggressive. You may want to consider a longer interval.

Comment: Will this run even if the app is not open? It seems like the app has to be open to trigger the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your onreceive method of Broadcastreceiver-

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {   
     //you need to acquire the power lock 
     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
     wl.acquire();

     //do you things

    //then release the lock
    wl.release();
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. Still not firing, not sure why.